# Does converting adjacency matrix representation of graph of size $n \times n$ to adjacency list always require $O(n^2)$ time?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, asymptotics

Assume that I have the adjacency matrix representation of a graph in $0,1$ values. Does converting it to a corresponding adjacency list representation **always** have a time complexity of $O(n^2)$?

Answer (score 2):

"Nothing is always."

Without any prior knowledge, the worst case time-complexity of converting an adjacency matrix representation of a graph in 0,1 values to a corresponding adjacency list representation is $\Theta(n^2)$.

However, if we know the graph is a sparse matrix with number of edges $m=o(n^2)$ and its adjacency matrix is stored in some compressed format like Yale format, then we can expect a conversion takes $o(n^2)$ time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. An algorithm that converts an adjacency matrix to an adjacency list must always take $\Omega(n^2)$ time. Otherwise, there would be at least one entry of the matrix that is never read, and thus the algorithm would not know whether that edge should occur in the output (if the graph is directed). Thus, we could construct an input on which the algorithm produces the wrong result (by flipping the value of the matrix at an entry that is never read if it doesn't already produce a wrong result on that input). If the graph is undirected the same argument holds, we just have to observe that there are at least $n^2/2+1$ entries that are never read.